# MAX3232 CAE outputs -6V / +6V instead of -12V / +12V

Tags: rs232, max3232

I bought a GN801 GPS module from Stoton 
( http://www.stotoncn.com/gnssmodule/showproduct.php?lang=en&id=42 )

Power supply range is +5V.
There is an onboard MAX3232CAE that is supposed to output RS232 signal.

I need to connect this module to a third party system that only accept **RS232 with -12V / +12V signals levels**.

When viewing MAX3232CAE TX pin trace with an oscilloscope, i can see it outputs -6V / +6V signal.

- Wasn't MAX3232 supposed to output -12/ +12V signal, did i miss something here ?
- This GPS module also exists in version with TTL output rather than RS232, if i go with TTL outputs (0-5V) how could i get a real -12V / +12V RS232 output since MAX3232 looks not to do so ?

Thank you very much for your lights on this and best regards,

[image]

Comment: RS-232 is specifying voltage level for anything between (+/-)3-15V. So your device which is not accepting +/-6 is not RS-232 compliant (BTW, where is it saing it is not accepting it?).

Comment: The [MAX3232 datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf) says it's only guaranteed to provide +/-5V RS232 outputs, so the +/-6V you're seeing is good. And as Eugene has pointed out, this is still well within spec for RS232. It's your 'other device' that's non-compliant.

Answer (score 5):

> I need to connect this module to a third party system that only accept RS232 with -12V / +12V signals levels.

You will need to supply details of that device, and a copy of the documentation which leads to the conclusion that it *requires* those signal levels. That requirement is *not* part of RS-232.

> When viewing MAX3232CAE TX pin trace with an oscilloscope, i can see it outputs -6V / +6V signal.

Good.

> Wasn't MAX3232 supposed to output -12/ +12V signal

No, the [MAX3232 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf) shows that it outputs a *minimum* of +/-5 V (with 3k load) which meets the RS-232 specification (see TIA/EIA-232-F paragraph 2.1.6).

> This GPS module also exists in version with TTL output rather than RS232, if i go with TTL outputs (0-5V) how could i get a real -12V / +12V RS232 output since MAX3232 looks not to do so ?

+/-12 V is not "real" RS-232. Even a very old RS-232 driver, like the MC1488, is not guaranteed to output +/- 12 V. Although it would be possible to achieve those signal levels, it might require a design using discrete components or boosted power rail voltages for an old RS-232 driver.

In the distant past, +/-12 V was a common *maximum* RS-232 voltage level seen in real life. Perhaps the documentation you have for that "module" has been mistranslated or otherwise misinterpreted that this voltage is a *requirement*...